# erro left join linq

Tags: linq, code-first, database-first

Não consigo acessar os métodos de uma classe filha que foi criado usando database first:

```
namespace Dados
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class pessoa
    {
        public pessoa()
        {
            this.pessoa_endereco = new HashSet<pessoa_endereco>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string tipo { get; set; }
        public string razao_social { get; set; }
        public string nome_fantasia { get; set; }
        public string cpf_cnpj { get; set; }
        public string rg_insc_estadual { get; set; }
        public string insc_substituicao { get; set; }
        public string insc_municipal { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> data_expedicao_rg { get; set; }
        public string orgao_expedidor_rg { get; set; }

        public virtual administrador administrador { get; set; }
        public virtual banco banco { get; set; }
        public virtual cliente cliente { get; set; }
        public virtual filial filial { get; set; }
        public virtual fornecedor fornecedor { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<pessoa_endereco> pessoa_endereco { get; set; }
        public virtual usuario usuario { get; set; }
        public virtual vendedor vendedor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

a classe filha é:

```
namespace Dados
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class pessoa_endereco
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int pessoa_id { get; set; }
        public string logradouro { get; set; }
        public string numero { get; set; }
        public string complemento { get; set; }
        public string ponto_referencia { get; set; }
        public string cep { get; set; }
        public string bairro { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> cidade_id { get; set; }
        public string nome_contato { get; set; }
        public string telefone_1 { get; set; }
        public string ramal_telefone_1 { get; set; }
        public string telefone_2 { get; set; }
        public string ramal_telefone_2 { get; set; }
        public string celular { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }

        public virtual cidade cidade { get; set; }
        public virtual pessoa pessoa { get; set; }
    }
}
```

controller:

```
        takeeatEntities context = new takeeatEntities();

        var pessoas = context.pessoa
                     .GroupJoin(context.pessoa_endereco, p => p.id, a => a.pessoa_id, (p, a) => new { p, a })
                     .SelectMany(a => a.a.DefaultIfEmpty(), (p, a) => new PessoaDados
                     {
                         Id = p.p.id,
                         Razao_social = p.p.razao_social,
                         p.a. //não tem acesso aos metodos da pessoa_endereço
                     })
                     .ToList();
```

como posso acessar esses métodos no controller, pois quando coloco p.a. ele não traz nenhum campo de pessoa_endereço, se faço p.p. me traz todos os campos somente da classe pai pessoa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta mais olhando para o teu código o que me parece é que vc não fez a instancia correta na classe filha, para depois poderes pegar os seus atributos então vamos ver como ficaria:

CLASSE PAI :

```
public partial class pessoa
{       
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    public string razao_social { get; set; }
    public string nome_fantasia { get; set; }
    public string cpf_cnpj { get; set; }
    public string rg_insc_estadual { get; set; }
    public string insc_substituicao { get; set; }
    public string insc_municipal { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> data_expedicao_rg { get; set; }
    public string orgao_expedidor_rg { get; set; }

    public virtual administrador administrador { get; set; }
    public virtual banco banco { get; set; }
    public virtual cliente cliente { get; set; }
    public virtual filial filial { get; set; }
    public virtual fornecedor fornecedor { get; set; }          
    public virtual usuario usuario { get; set; }
    public virtual vendedor vendedor { get; set; }

}
```

CLASSE FILHA :

```
  public partial class pessoa_endereco : pessoa  // neste caso a classe filha herda os atributos da classe pai
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int pessoa_id { get; set; }
            public string logradouro { get; set; }
            public string numero { get; set; }
            public string complemento { get; set; }
            public string ponto_referencia { get; set; }
            public string cep { get; set; }
            public string bairro { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> cidade_id { get; set; }
            public string nome_contato { get; set; }
            public string telefone_1 { get; set; }
            public string ramal_telefone_1 { get; set; }
            public string telefone_2 { get; set; }
            public string ramal_telefone_2 { get; set; }
            public string celular { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public virtual cidade cidade { get; set; }
            public virtual pessoa pessoa { get; set; }
        }
```

neste caso com a classe filha vc consegue ter acesso a todos os atributos do pai que sejam públicos, então vc não precisa repetir na classe filha tudo aquilo que seja comum na classe pai. Na classe filha vc poe apenas os atributos particulares de cada pessoa_endereço.

depois disso vc pode fazer com que a classe que tenha acesso. Espero ter ajudado tente fazer assim. Tenha cuidado pois o código não foi testado olhe direito para eliminar os erros.

Comment: Ainda não consigo acessar as propriedades da classe pessoa_endereço, mas notei por acaso que consigo acessar de todas as public virtual que foram declaradas, dai inclui ela na lista e apareceu, com certeza nao estou fazendo da maneira correta, mas o problema agora é outro. Vi que database-first apesar de todo o galho que quebra não é a solução idelal, porque se altero um campo no banco e dou um update no Model.edmx ele vai apagar tudo que fiz, embora ache que code-first vai me dar muito trabalho porque nao vou poder mais mexer no banco diretamente para fazer alterações, ele é a melhor solução!

Comment: Mas marquei a sua resposta como correta porque me deu uma luz no que fazer, muito obrigado pela ajuda!